# About vector and angle (Dot product?)

Tags: vector, geometry, angle, vertices

Hello I have a question about this
[image]

It's from http://www.vitutor.com/geometry/vec/angle_vectors.html

To find AB->, from what i saw it uses this: AB = -A + B = (-6,0)+(3,5)=(-3,5)

My Question is, is it possible to find coordinate from more vertices like ABC-> or ABCD-> or ABCD....n->, something like that?

Comment: This is just simple addition of vectors, nothing to do with dot products or angles.

Comment: your question does not make any sense to me. You want to obtain angles of triangle (or polygon) or some kind of point coordinate? Which is it title and first part of OP suggest angles and the rest is weird and unrelated to it...  btw Yes you can use dot product to obtain all the angles for any polygon ...

Comment: Yes, i guess it doesn't make sense, it's more about coordinate

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Angle between 3 consequent points `p0,p1,p2` is computed like this

```
ang = acos((p1-p0).(p2-p1))/(|p1-p0|.|p2-p1|)
```

in **2D** it is:

```
ang = acos((x1-x0).(x2-x1)+(y1-y0).(y2-y1))/sqrt((x1-x0).(x2-x1).(x1-x0).(x2-x1)+(y1-y0).(y2-y1).(y1-y0).(y2-y1))
```

[image: img]